# Error message: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 250, 259

Tags: r, dataframe, size, sample

I got this problem when I try to export some data:

```
write.csv(avvik <- cbind(u.s, j.k, k.e), "avvik.txt")
```

I've already understood that the problem probably lies in "your trying to set the sample size from some groups equal to zero". This is what I did learn from another post here at the forum. But I'm quite new at using R, so what does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you supply more code or clarity, more people will be able to help you. From the title of your post, it appears you are trying to write a csv file where the columns are different lengths.

Try running: `length(u.s); length(j.k); length(k.e)`

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try to be more clear next time I make a question. When it comes to my problem however, a friend of mine also told me it could have to do with column lenght.But my columns all seem to have the same lenght, so I guess I'll have to see if something else can be wrong.